# boost::posix_time::ptime to UTC8601?

Tags: c++, datetime

Is there a way to convert an object of type `boost::posix_time::ptime` to format [UTC8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean by convert.. If you just want to see the ISO string, use

```
std::string to_iso_string(ptime)
```

or

```
std::string to_iso_extended_string(ptime)
```

or to pull out the date and time components as date and time_durations use:

```
date d(ptime.date())
```

and

```
time_duration td(ptime.time_of_day())
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [boost.date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library especially for the `set_iso_format()` and `set_iso_extended_format()` methods referenced by new [date_time IO streaming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) system.